# Loading associated JSON elements separately on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

Currently I'm loading in a large JSON object from our ldap server to show all the groups and members. I'm able to parse the entire file and separate out groups and members, but not their association. What I want to do is load the groups (paginated), then have a user click on the group to load only those associated users. However, I'm having issues figuring out how to do that. What follows is what I'm using to load all the groups and members. I do have another endpoint available, (ldap/groups/members) if that helps.

```
$(function displayGroupItems() {
$('.group-submit').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'ldap/groups',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.entries, function(i, dn) {
                output = '<span>'+ dn.dn +'</span>';
                content = '<a>'+dn.member+'</a>';
                $(output).appendTo('#dropdown');
                $(content).appendTo('.ldap-users');
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: So the `ldap/groups` endpoint returns member names, but not their information?  Is this accurate?

Comment: No. Sorry. It returns everything inside the entries. So the full dn, dc, ou, uids, everything. I specified the dn.dn to just return groups.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying you have the complete user information, and now on click of the user, you want to show their associated user information that you have already retrieved?

Comment: Correct. I have the complete group and user information. However, I want to separate it out for easier readability and not load the 10000 entries we have at once. I can paginate the groups thats fine, but I don't want the users to load until a group is clicked and then only that groups users load.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well sure you could do that.  It would make sense to have an endpoint return just a reference to the users and then load the users on an interaction.  Though now I'm slightly confused about what the specific question is that you are asking.

Comment: I guess the question is, how to do return the associated users with the groups  once clicked. Sure we can have an endpoint called ldap/groups/members, but I'm not sure what I need to put in the the jQuery/JavaScript to make sure I'm only returning associated group members.

Comment: Give your <a> a class select the a.class and add an click handler (like the one for group-submit - almost a duplicate of the displayGroupItems function). In the click handler query the endpoint /ldap/groups/members. You mix a lot of stuff in your questions which makes it hard to answer these.

Comment: @Edub I redid my question, which hopefully clarifies everything.